# What does "existence failed (20: Not a directory) while logging request" error log on Nginx mean?

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm, roundcube

At an webserver with Nginx and php-fpm and Roundcube I'm seeing entries like this:

```
2016/10/12 11:22:55 [error] 342342#0: *234242 testing "/some/path" existence failed (20: Not a directory) while logging request, client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: server.example.org, request: "GET /webmail/?_task=mail&_action=getunread&_remote=1&_unlock=0&_=2422423423 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9001", host: "server.example.org", referrer: "https://server.example.org/foo"
```

inside error.log of Nginx. What does this line mean?

Comment: It means that `/some/path` is not a directory where nginx could start writing your log file. I cannot tell you why nginx gives that error message because you give no information about `/some/path`. Include the output of `ls -ld /some/path` and nginx configuration in your question for further help.

Comment: Well, actually I don't have an explicit logging statement here. Is in such cases alias/root might used in stead for?

Comment: There is always some logging set up in nginx. You need to look through the complete configuration, not just the virtual host configuration.

Comment: I'm aware of. But I meant that there is no special logging setup for this virtual host where apparently the path is coming from. So it's the root of the vhost and it's only used in that vhost.

Comment: Actually now I read to the end of the line, the request goes into upstream FastCGI, so your web application generates this error.

Answer (score 3):

You have used an `access_log` directive which contains variables. When you do this, nginx checks for the existence of the document `root` when logging each request. The `root` must exist and must be a directory. In this case, the error means that you have set the `root` to a file, not a directory. To fix the problem, set `root` to a directory.

Answer (score -1):

like this ?

```
2019/06/22 04:40:49 [error] 127592#0: *31196255 testing "/etc/nginx/html" existence failed (2: No such file or directory) while logging request,
```

I have encountered this problem, in fact, this directory is stored in nginx default html, just like `50x.html`, `index.html`. If you try `mkdir /etc/nginx/html` , the log will be printed normally.

Comment: No, not like that. This is a completely different error.